# Как скомпилировать проект Android Studio, подписанный ключом, чтобы протестировать его на устройстве

Tags: android, android-studio

Мне скинули проект, но скомпилировать я его не могу т.к. студия выдает ошибку:

```
Keystore file 'путь к файлу ключа.jks' not found for signing config 'config'.
```

Мне обязательно необходимо спрашивать у создателя проекта файл ключа или же можно скомпилировать без ключа подписи?

Comment: Вы можете создать свой ключ и подписать им, либо собрать debug версию - она автоматически подписывается дебажным ключом. В обоих случаях приложение можно установить и использовать, но заменить им оригинальное можно только с потерей сохранённых данных.

Comment: Либо как вариант на скорую руку - просто удалить `config` подписи из build.gradle:)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov да, я так и сделал, это помогло. Был бы рад, если вы ответили бы на вопрос не комментарием, отмечу его, может быть, пригодится кому-нибудь)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть три пути решения Вашей задачи:

1. Удалить из файла build.gradle Вашего приложения следующие строки:

   ```
   signingConfigs {
       signing {// все, что внутри signing может отличаться в разных проектах*
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       }
   }
   ```

   При этом `signing`, использованный ниже подсветит студия, удалите так же места использования и все должно запуститься.
2. Запускать debug конфигурацию, пример фрагмента build.gradle ниже. После внесения изменений и синхронизации проекта в gradle, в студии необходимо будет в левом нижнем углу (по умолчанию) открыть вкладку Build Variants и там переключиться на debug

   ```
   buildTypes {
       debug { // вот эту секцию нужно добавить
           debuggable true
           applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
       }
       release {
           debuggable false
           minifyEnabled false
           signingConfig signingConfigs.signing // вот это пришлось бы удалить в методе 1
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   ```
3. Вы можете в секции `signing` прописать свои данные, это самый заморочный способ, если делаете впервые.

Использование третьего способа может показаться странным, однако, необходимо понимать, что есть сервисы (например, гугла), которые не работают в приложениях без подписи, в том числе в дебажной версии.

P.s. Все изменения предлагаются для файла build.gradle модуля приложения (по умолчанию app)